# JQuery/Javascript Accessing a table with checkbox and retrieve the id of one specific <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Trying to :

1. Verify if a checkbox got selected.
   2.Retrieve the  value.
2. Save a value in an array.
   So my array would have the following values: [1,21,111]

What him I missing, any guidance would be appreciated.
After I've figured this out... will go and create another array to store the automationName.

```js
var SelectedItems = [];
$('.btn1').on('click', function() {
  SelectedItems.length = 0;
  $('#flowtable tbody tr').each(function() {

    //    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    //    if ($('.scheduleMe').is(':checked')) {        
    if ($('td .scheduleMe').is(':checked')) {
      SelectedItems.push($(this).attr("id"));
    }
  });

  console.log('Checked #' + SelectedItems.length);
  console.log("list 2= " + SelectedItems);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>jQuery Crash Course</h1>
</header>
<div id="container">
  <form id="form">
    <table id="flowtable">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="selected">
          <td id="1"></td>
          <td class="automationName"> automation 1</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="scheduleMe" name="vehicle1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="21"></td>
          <td class="automationName">automation 21</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="scheduleMe" name="vehicle21"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="111"></td>
          <td class="automationName">automation 111</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="scheduleMe" name="vehicle111"></td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn1">check list box</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, give the checkboxes a value which is the `id` they relate to, not the the sibling/parent `td`.

From there you can simplify your logic by using `map()` to build an array of the selected values only once, when the button is clicked, not having to maintain additions/deletions from the higher scoped array when a change is made.

Below is a working example. Note the use of `label` elements to make the clickable area of the checkboxes bigger.

```js
$('.btn1').on('click', function() {
  let selectedItems = $('.scheduleMe:checked').map((i, el) => el.value).get();
  console.log(selectedItems);

  // work with the array as required here, eg. pass to a fnuction for processing...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>jQuery Crash Course</h1>
</header>
<div id="container">
  <form id="form">
    <table id="flowtable">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="selected">
          <td id="1"></td>
          <td class="automationName"><label for="vehicle1">automation 1</label></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="scheduleMe" name="vehicle1" id="vehicle1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="21"></td>
          <td class="automationName"><label for="vehicle21">automation 21</label></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" value="21" class="scheduleMe" name="vehicle21" id="vehicle21" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="111"></td>
          <td class="automationName"><label for="vehicle111">automation 111</label></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" value="111" class="scheduleMe" name="vehicle111" id="vehicle111" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn1">check list box</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

If, for whatever reason, you can't change the HTML, then you can read the value from the `td` in `map()` like this:

```js
let selectedItems = $('.scheduleMe:checked').map((i, el) => $(el).closest('tr').find('td[id]').prop('id')).get();
```

Comment: Thank you for the code the first is working.

Comment: Not able to change HTML, so if try the second suggestion:

Comment: ```let selectedItems = $('.scheduleMe:checked').map((i, el) => $(el).closest('tr').find('td[id]').prop('id')).get();     ``` is returning an empty string?

Comment: I went in Debug andsaw that it had the value... but when we console.log(SelectedItems) , it was empty.... not sure why

Comment: The code works in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/x4L629am/. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks again It look like I made a mistake it's working now. Many Thanks.

Comment: Will now try to implement in JSF env.

Comment: HOw would I return the text of the second <TD>... like "automation 1","automation 21","automation 111"     ....

Comment: Been trying for the last few hours and it return an object...

Comment: selectName2 = $('.scheduleMe:checked').map((i, el) => $(el).closest('tr').first('td').text()).get();             is giving the 2 values.... I only want the first one

Comment: `$(el).closest('tr').find('td[id]').next().next().text()`

Comment: Many thanks to you Rory McCrossan great example and it all work :)

Answer (score 0):

- `callMe()` is a function that is handling all logic.
- I am just checking if the checkBox is checked or not by using default property of input type checkbox `checked`.
- If it is checked then we are pushing it in array, just making sure the item is not already there by using `includes()`. method.

```js
var SelectedItems = [];
const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("#flowtable tr");
const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("#flowtable tr td > input");
const btn = document.querySelectorAll("#btn1");

function callMe() {
  checkBoxes.forEach(checkBox => {
    if (checkBox.checked) {
      const currentParent = checkBox.parentElement.parentElement;
      const getId = currentParent.querySelectorAll("td[id]")[0];
      const val = getId.id;
      if (SelectedItems.includes(val)) return;
      SelectedItems.push(val);
    }
  })
  if (SelectedItems === undefined || SelectedItems.length == 0) {
    // array does not exist or is empty
    console.log("No checkbox is checked.");
  } else {
    console.log(SelectedItems);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>jQuery Crash Course</h1>
</header>
<div id="container">
  <form id="form">
    <table id="flowtable">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="selected">
          <td id="1"></td>
          <td class="automationName"> automation 1</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="scheduleMe" name="vehicle1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="21"></td>
          <td class="automationName">automation 21</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="scheduleMe" name="vehicle21"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="111"></td>
          <td class="automationName">automation 111</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="scheduleMe" name="vehicle111"></td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" id="btn1" onclick="callMe();">check list box</button>
  </form>
</div>
```